# Cassandra Connection Error: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, cassandra

I'm trying to set up Cassandra and I'm following the cassandra setup here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html, but everytime I try to connect, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread.
```

Based off of this issue https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-38, it looks like it may be a Netty conflict, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm using Play 2.2.3 for scala,the Datastax java driver 2.0.2, and Cassandra 2.0.3.

My code:

```
class SimpleClient {
  private var cluster: Cluster = null

  def connect(node: String): Unit = {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();

    val metaData = cluster.getMetadata();
    println(s"########## connected to cluster: ${metaData.getClusterName}")
  }

  def close() = {
    cluster.close
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix the issue, so I abandoned Play for Scalatra. I used the exact same code as above, and I'm now connecting to Cassandra fine. It must have been some Play dependency that didn't agree with the datastax driver.